# Single Instance in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

What is the best practice for only allowing one instance of a Silverlight 5 application open in the browser at a time by an individual user/client?

If the user opens a second instance of the in browser silverlight application, they should recieve a message indicating there is another instance open and that they cannot continue.

Comment: Does your application have any sort of authentication mechanism ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ensure that a Silverlight OOB app only has a single instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824374/how-to-ensure-that-a-silverlight-oob-app-only-has-a-single-instance)

Comment: Note: not exact same title, but exact same solution (as OOB and IB won't differ).

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of classes in Silverlight that allow local applications to communicate.

Take a look here : [Communication Between Local Silverlight-Based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833063%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)